# SQL cohort retention

Tags: sql, postgresql, retention

The below question is actually copied from the other post and asking for Tableau answer but I would like to use SQL to prevent from performance problem.

I'm trying to calculate user retention rates across dates and for the last 14 days. For example, if 44 users arrive for the first time on September 16th, and then 19 of them show up again on September 17th, our day 1 retention for those September 16th users is 19/44. And if 41 users showed up for the first time on September 17th and 24 of those came back again on September 18th, then the September 17th 1 day retention would be 24/41. And if 18 users returned on September 18th who arrived for the first time on September 16th, then their 2 day retention would be 18/44.

The final outcome I would like to have is shown as below. I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the retention for Cohort Day by date. In addition, the table login contains the following columns, TimeStamp, userid, gamelabel, and play_time.

Login Table

```
        TimeStamp      | Userid    | GameLabel  | playtime | 
-----------------------+-----------+------------+-----------
 2016-09-16 21:00:24+8 |      af07 |         LL |    60010 |   
 2016-09-16 21:00:25+8 |      9dbe |         YY |    60016 |            
 2016-09-16 21:01:24+8 |      af07 |         SS |    60009 |
```

The Final Outcome I would like to have

```
Retention| Today  | Today- 1 Day|Today- 2 Day...|Today-12 Day  |Today-13 Day
---------+--------+-------------+---------------+------------------+--------
         |09/29/16|  09/28/16   |    09/27/16...|     09/17/16 |   09/16/16
      0  |        |             |               |         41/41|     44/44
      1  |        |             |               |         24/41|     19/44
      2  |        |             |               |              |     18/44
      3  |        |             |               |              |
      7  |        |             |               |              |
```

[Table Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN4qW.jpg)

[The Final Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyX3W.jpg)

Comment: Google "pivot query"

Comment: Images are useless to reproduce the data. Post text.